# is there a way to copy some values from array to input field without ng-repeat in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, forms, input

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat = "person in people">
<td>{{person.name}}</td>
<td>{{person.surname}}</td>
<td>{{person.gender}}</td>
<td ng-click="edit(person)>Edit</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This table was built with data from an array object like this:

```
people = [{
    name: Simon,
    surname: Tim,
    gender: Male
    },
    {
    name: Natan,
    surname: Burns,
    gender: Male
    }];
```

So the question is: when I press 'Edit' button, I need to copy the values from table to form in other section of the page:

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="name">
<input type="text" value="surname">
<input type="text" value="gender"> 
</form>
```

Eveything is simple if I build the form taking data from array using ng-repeat (for example, when I press edit, I can copy the data in a temporary array and with ng-repeat I can build the input fields with the values I want), but is there a way to do that without ng-repeat? How can I bind the "edit" button with the copy of values in the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by assigning an object variable, eg

```
$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.people[selectedIndex];
```

(where selectedIndex is the index of the selected person.

Then your input form can be like this

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedPerson.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedPerson.surname">
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedPerson.gender"> 
</form>
```

And your update/save script has the data in an object already for saving